# emmet expansion not aligned/indented as I expected

Tags: emmet

If I expand this:

```
#main>#nav>ul>li>{My Web Host}
```

I get this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>My Web Host</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it's good.

If I expand this:

```
#main>#nav>ul>li>{My Web Host}>ul>li>
```

I get this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>My Web Host
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Although the closing tag of the first li is after the last ul I was hoping it would be on the next line aligned under it's opening tag.

Comment: So what's the issue? Only the alignment?

Comment: That's it only the alignment.  Is this a limitation of emmet?

Comment: Can you explain what do you expect here so I can help you out with that?

Comment: As stated earlier I was expecting the closing tag of the first li to be aligned under it's opening tag.  If you look you'll see the other closing tags with the exception of the closing tag in the final li are all symmetrically arranged below the opening tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This abbreviation is incorrect at `{My Web Host}>ul`: you’re trying to put block element (`ul`) inside implicit inline element (`{My Web Host}`). In this case, you have to place `ul` *after* text node, e.g. use `+` operator.

Correct abbreviation is
`#main>#nav>ul>li>{My Web Host}+ul>li`